# Make mysql table `Id` field binary using doctrine 2.4.7

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, md5

I have a table with lots of param columns, and a `count` column. Records can have duplicates on all columns excluding `count`, so now DB gets lots of unnecessary  records.

The idea is:

1) make `id` column binary and with each insert set it to md5(param1 . param2...)

2) if the insert action gets "ON DUPLICATE KEY" (which is md5 of params) -> do not insert new, and UPDATE existing record via `count` = `count` + $count.

finnally, i think, SQL query will look like this

`INSERT INTO log_urls (id, server, channel, userCount)
VALUES (3cb27ceaa9ea4649d661090de5d47043, 'www.server.net', 10, 1900)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userCount=userCount + 1900;`

So, how can i make doctrine understand binary `id` column??

Comment: Doctrine supports binary types : http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html. Also be aware that after MySQL 5.5.3, the MD5 function returns a non-binary string in the connection collation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5.

Comment: completely agree.. but project has dependencies that restricts doctrine < 2.5